# Select logged in user's ID using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am new to using PDO and was wondering how I would select the logged in user's id from my phpMyAdmin database.

My initialization file is...

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project', 'root', '');
```

Here is my users table layout:

[image]

Comment: SELECT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html with a WHERE clause.

Comment: I know `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");` is like this but when I put something like `$loggedinQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");` for PDO it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get the users info where their `id` is the same as `user_id`

You might do something like this;

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=:id');
//using bindParam helps prevent SQL Injection
$query->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
$query->execute();
//$results is now an associative array with the result
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I wasn't sure how `user_id` is set so I just used bindParam just in case.

Comment: Thank you, it's definitely working, just not calling the exact user's id. Probably something with my other code that I'll have to look into.